# PHP function pass by reference not working out of function scope

Tags: php, function, reference

Why does this code print 1 and not anything else? The function passes by reference, but the reference seems not to work out of the function scope. Why?

```
<?php
function a(&$a, &$b) {  
     $a =& $b;  
}
$a = 1;
$b = 2;
a($a, $b);
$b = 3;
print $a;
?>
```

Comment: [References in PHP are not pointers in C](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.arent.php).

Answer (score 0):

When you modify the variable **a** within the function it's not modified externally because it is not defined as a global variable, so the value of **a** remains **1** as you declared before calling the function. If you try to add `global $a;` before `$a =& $b;` you'll obtain as output `$a = 2;`

Comment: But $a was passed by reference... shouldn't need to be defined as global. For instance, if you simply do $a = 2, it preserves its value outside. That's why the reported behaviour is indeed really strange.

Comment: @revo found this http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.arent.php

Answer (score 0):

Change `$a =& $b;` to `$GLOBALS['a'] =& $b;`

OR

```
function a(&$a, &$b) {  
    $a =& $b;  
    return $a;
}
$a = 1;
$b = 2;
print a($a, $b);
```